# How to call a method inside my 'SKScene' from 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, skscene, public-method

I've a method in my SKScene as:

```
  func someTypeMethod() {
      print("someTypeMethod...")
  }
```

I tried to call it from my 'ViewController' as:

```
  if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
      scene.someTypeMethod()
  }
```

But Xcode is saying `'Value of type SKScene has no member 'scene.someTypeMethod'`

I've even tried to make the method 'public' and 'class'. But still the error appears. So, how can I call such methods in my 'SKScene' from its 'ViewController'?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Is `someTypeMethod()` declared on an extension of SKScene or on a subclass?

If it is on a subclass, you need to change to

```
  if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") as? MySKSceneSubclass {
      scene.someTypeMethod()
  }
```

The compiler only knows that scene has the native SKScene methods if you don't tell it which proper subclass it's expecting.  Making it a class method means you'd call `SKScene.someTypeMethod()`, rather than `scene.someTypeMethod()`, but then it won't have access to your scene's data.